# Returning a list of words in alphabetical order - reading from files

Tags: python, file, csv

For this code, I need to return a list of all unique words (words that only appear once in the file). Here is some of my code:

```
    words = []
    with open(self.filepath, 'r') as f:
        for l in f:
            new_word = l.split()

            words.append(new_word)
    return words
```

A word is defined as any text that is separated by whitespace (spaces, newlines, or tabs). In addition to adding unique words to a list, I need to have them all made lowercase and in alphabetical order. I'm stuck on how I should do this. We do not have access to the file.

Comment: [``str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower).

Comment: You cant user .lower() on l.split() because it's a list object.

Comment: You don't need to lower a list.

Comment: @jchillin111: Call `lower` *before* you `split`.

Comment: Also, `l.split()` is indeed a list object - pay close attention to that, and see what is getting stored in `words` (as in, print out `words` and see what exactly is getting appended to it).

Comment: Thanks all! Everyone helped out. Special thanks to @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 1):

Dedup by storing to a `set`, and only convert to a sorted `list` at the end:

```
def load_words(self):
    words = set()  # Use set for accumulation without dups
    with open(self.filepath) as f:
        for l in f:
            new_words = l.lower().split()  # Convert to lowercase before splitting

            words.update(new_words)  # Add all new words in bulk as individual words, not single list of words for line
    return sorted(words)  # Convert unordered set to sorted list of words
```

Comment: Wow, this almost fixed it! I realized some words are listed as 'so' and some as 'so,' - we need to have it so commas, periods, and other punctuation is removed. so that it wont add in two words that are the same 'so' and 'so,' - it should just be 'so' - does this question make sense?

Comment: @jchillin111: Yeah, the problem there is that splitting on whitespace doesn't strip punctuation. Sometimes you *want* to strip punctuation, sometimes you don't (e.g. `it's` is a different word from `its`). If you just want to remove leading and trailing punctuation (but not internal punctuation within a word), and you're okay with handling ASCII only, just add an import `from string import punctuation` to the top of the module, and add `new_words = [w.strip(punctuation) for w in new_words]` between the `split` and the `update` line.

Comment: Thanks. This works great! I'm gonna go read up on the documentation to understand more of how this works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use list comprehension

```py
words = set()
with open(self.filepath, 'r') as f:
    # value can be anything, just added 1
    words.update({str(i.lower()):1 for i in f.split()}.keys())

return sorted(words)
```

Answer (score -1):

First do .lower() and then .split()

```
new_word = l.lower().strip().split(' ')
```

You can also add an if statement to catch the whitespace

```
if l is ' ' or l is '\n':
  # catch whitespace
```

Comment: Thanks. any advice for alphabetical order?

Comment: This only splits on spaces and no other kinds of whitespace, as was asked. [The documentation on `split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) may help.